# Adding a Lambda function into Kinesis Firehose via Cloudformation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I want to add a Lambda function to my Kinesis Firehose to transform the source data as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html).

Looking at the [Cloudformation Template for Kinesis firehose](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream.html), I don't see an option for that,

```
Type: "AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream"
Properties: 
  DeliveryStreamName: String
  DeliveryStreamType: String
  ElasticsearchDestinationConfiguration:
    ElasticsearchDestinationConfiguration
  ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration:
    ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration
  KinesisStreamSourceConfiguration:
    KinesisStreamSourceConfiguration
  RedshiftDestinationConfiguration:
    RedshiftDestinationConfiguration
  S3DestinationConfiguration:
    S3DestinationConfiguration
```

How do I setup the CF template to have a Lambda function process the input for Kinesis Firehose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to achieve this via [ProcessingConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-processingconfiguration.html) which is available for ES, S3 and Redshift destination configs. Should look something like the following:

```
"ElasticsearchDestinationConfiguration": {
...
   "ProcessingConfiguration": {
         "Enabled": "true",
         "Processors": [
           {
             "Parameters": [
               {
                 "ParameterName": "LambdaArn",
                 "ParameterValue": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789:function:cw-transformer:$LATEST"
               }
             ],
             "Type": "Lambda"
           }
         ]
       }
...
}
```

Comment: Do you have it in YAML? Been tearing my hair off, I don't understand why Amazon cannot provide examples of how to write it.

Comment: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream.html), at the bottom are examples